# How to reference two ForeignKeys in one model

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key

I want to accomplish the following:
I have three classes derived from an abstract class:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  ...
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class TypA(Person):
  ...

class TypB(Person):
  ...

class TypC(Person):
  ...
```

In another class I would like to reference TypA and TypB as a Foreign Key, something like this:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
  worker = models.ForeignKey(TypA or TypB)
```

Since it is not possible to declare two different models as a Foreign Key I am on the look for solutions.
I read about Generic Foreign Keys; but I am unsure how to apply that to my model.

Another idea is to use the `limit_choices_to` declaration for ForeignKeys.

```py
worker = models.ForeignKey(Person, limit_choices_to={??})
```

But this is not possible as it seems:

```
Field defines a relation with model 'Person', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Why is person abstract? Why don't they just inherit from it as a normal model?

Comment: Because there is no person per se; just special types of person and that is why I want to map this in the DB as well.

Comment: But you could still leave it as a normal class and use that as the foreign key. Then you could access it through `TypA` or `TypB`

Comment: Ok, lets say I leave it as a normal class: How to combine both classes TypA and TypB but not TypC in another class (Project)?

Comment: You would need to deal with that in your code as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Django `ForeignKey` field translates to a database foreign key. Your `Person` model is abstract, so that one doesn't exist in the database, so there can be no foreign keys to that one.

Likewise a database foreign key can only reference one table, not two.

If you really want a flexible relation to more than one kind of table, the only possibility I see is Django's [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

You also want to limit the kinds of models you can point at. For that you'd best look at [How can I restrict Django's GenericForeignKey to a list of models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335986/how-can-i-restrict-djangos-genericforeignkey-to-a-list-of-models) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to reference your abstract class(like JAVA):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Person)


#in your code:
worker = TypeA()
worker.save()
proj = Project()
proj.worker = worker
proj.save()
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not possible as this error message suggests:
`Field defines a relation with model 'Person', which is either not installed, or is abstract.`