# ForeignKey with multiple models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

If I have two models

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    # properties...

class modelB(models.Model):
    # properties
```

and I want both models to an `images` field, then how would I write the image model? If it was just one then I think it would be like:

```
class Image(models.Model):
   image = models.ForeignKey(modelA)
```

So if I also wanted `modelB` to have images, then how would that work? Would I have to write `ImageA` and `ImageB`?

Comment: Why don't you just define an `ImageField` on each model? Django already has a built-in `ImageField` which you can use with: `image = models.ImageField()`.

Comment: Right but I want the ability to have multiple images per model

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you want to use [generic foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Image(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Now your `Image` model can have foreign keys to either of your other models, and you can have multiple images associated with each object. The documentation I have linked to above explains how to use this setup and query objects etc.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6336509/3955830) for how you can limit this so that you can foreign key to only specific models.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Go the other way with the relationship.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    # properties

class modelA(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, vars=vals)

class modelB(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, vars=vals)
```

You can then query as

```
modelB.image
modelA.image

image.modelA_set.all()
image.modelB_set.all()
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought you usually declared ForeignKey inversely?

Comment: I'm not really aware of that rule. I structure my data to improve performance and enable lookups.

In this case, the Image model is a one-to-many, I'm assuming that multiple instances of each model could refer to the same image.  If you're trying to declare that association in that model, you run into this exact problem: How do I make this work without writing a bunch of redundant tables with redundant code? 

The answer is to make the association in the other direction.