# Generic Foreign Key with computed content type instead of fk to content type model

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes, generic-foreign-key

The simplest case of creating a generic foreign key is like this:

```
class ModelWithGFK(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

But in my case there are other fields which I can infer the content type from, so adding a `content_type` FK is both redundant and prone to cause inconsistency over time. So I tried this:

```
class ModelWithGFK(models.
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    @property
    def content_type(self):
        # Figure out which content type this instance should have FK to
        return ContentType.objects.get(..........)
```

but seems like GFK class only accepts the content type argument to be a foreign key:

> ```
> def _check_content_type_field(self):
>     """
>     Check if field named `field_name` in model `model` exists and is a
>     valid content_type field (is a ForeignKey to ContentType).
>     """
> ```

Is there a workaround (perhaps via overriding GFK and some of its methods like `get_content_type`) or I shall give in, add the FK and live in a constant fear of inconsistency and agony of knowing about this (tiny) inevitable redundancy?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335986/how-can-i-restrict-djangos-genericforeignkey-to-a-list-of-models