# Allow one and only one field from fields subset in Django model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, model

I have a model Model. This model have multiple attributes, three of them are: `domaintld`, `subdomain`, `url` - `OneToOneField`s.

I'm trying to allow one and only one from these fields to be non empty.

My approach works but I'm curious if it's there a better way to do this (I use **PostgreSQL**).

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    self.clean()
    super(Model, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

def clean(self):
    super(Model, self).clean()

    if not(((bool(self.url) ^ bool(self.domaintld)) ^ bool(self.subdomain)) and not(self.url and self.domaintld and self.subdomain)):
        raise exceptions.ValidationError("One and only one field can be used: url,domaintld,subdomain")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have something like this in your `models.py`:

```
class DomainTLD(models.Model):
    # attributes and methods

class Subdomain(models.Model):
    # attributes and methods

class URL(models.Model):
    # attributes and methods

class MyModel(models.Model):
    domaintld = models.OneToOneField(DomainTLD)
    subdomain = models.OneToOneField(Subdomain)
    url = models.OneToOneField(URL)
    # other attributes and methods
```

I'd suggest using django [`contenttypes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) and refactoring like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

and scrap the `save` and `clean` method. Now `MyModel` can have a relation with any model, be it `DomainTLD`, `Subdomain` or `URL` - `content_type` points to the model, `object_id` holds the object ID and `content_object`, which won't become a field in the database, will be used to retrieve the object.

This is much cleaner way and you can get rid of that obscure `clean` method.
You can further enhance it and limit the choices for `content_type` only to those you wish. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335986/how-can-i-restrict-djangos-genericforeignkey-to-a-list-of-models) explains that.