# how to create a model object that can handle a single foreign key for people and companies

Tags: python, django, inheritance, database-design, foreign-keys

I am creating an investor object.  Investors can be people or companies.

How can I create a model object that could represent either of these types in django?

Here are a few ways I was thinking:

**1. Having two non required foreign keys:**

```
     class Investor(models.Model):
     company = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
     customer = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Customer',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
     investor_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**2. Using a generic relation:**

```
class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    investor_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

**3. An abstract model that is inherited by both customer and company**

```
 class Entity(models.Model)

 class Customer(Entity)

 Class Company(Entity)
```

What is the most architecturally sound route to go which will not cause me a lot of problems down the line?

Comment: Why are you suspicious of the first option? Seems sound to me.

Comment: You can use the second option and [restrict the models allowed in the relation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6336509/1081569).